# Is SQL Injection possible in ORDER BY before LIMIT?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

I'm using MySQL with Mybatis library. And I found the code below:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
WHERE xxx
ORDER BY ${inputA} ${inputB} 
LIMIT #{inputC}
```

I know there are many ways to inject the `ORDER BY`, but haven't found any example of injection in `ORDER BY` with a `LIMIT` behind.
I tried `UNION SELECT`, but MySql doesn't allow to use `order by` in `UNION`

MySQL's default settings do not allow the execution of multiple statements at one time. Is there a way to make an injection by building only one statement?

Answer (score 2):

Prepared statements only deal with true data and not with static names like column of table names, because it is assumed that those static names can easily be controled. Furthermore, they are most often hardcoded in the code and only seldom come from external sources like user input.

But if you want to user to choose the columns to use for ordering, you **must** make sure that you only get valid column names, because injection is always possible.

Here, assuming col1 and col2 are valid column names and that the engine allows batched statements separated with semicolumns, you could have:

`inputA` = `col1`, `inputB` = `col2'; DROP; other_table; SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE xxx ORDER BY col1, col2`, `inputC` = `5`

Comment: Sorry for this late reply. And I forgot to write that MySQL stops from executing multiple statements in one time. I tried your examples and it failed with syntax error. So is there a way to make an injection by building only one statement?

Answer (score 1):

The `LIMIT` clause is still exploitable even when using `ORDER BY`.

You can find a detailed exploit based on the demonstration done by Maurycy Prodeus in [this article](https://pretagteam.com/question/sql-injection-and-the-limit-clause).

Comment: I've read the article. But it seems mainly illustrate ways to inject in `LIMIT` clause. However my case is to inject the `ORDER BY` clause before `LIMIT`, I can't inject `LIMIT` because the mybatis library wrap the inputC as string.